# spring validation message does not interpolate

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I'm trying to understand the validation messages and internationalization mechanism in spring and I wrote the following code:

```
public class Customer {

    @NotEmpty(message="{m1}")
    private String firstName;
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

Bean config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!--  Step 3: Add support for component scanning  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.demo"/>
<!--  Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<!--  Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver  -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames" value="resources/messages"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Resources filesystem structure:

```
-- resources
   messages.properties
   messages_it.properties
```

messages.properties:

```
m1=Not valid
```

messages_it.properties:

```
m1=Non valido
```

when I submit the form the error message that I get is: {m1}. Am I missing some code?

Comment: Try renaming your messages files like `ValidationMessages[...].properties`

Comment: renaming the files worked for me thanks. Can you show me a working example of how to use another filename and still have the message interpolation working correctly? I'm using tomcat 9, spring 2.7 and java 8

Comment: `Spring Validation` is based on `Hibernate Validation` : https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/